# Is "to wash the dishes" a wrong expression?

Tags: expressions

Q1.I heard a native speaker say that the expression "to **wash** the dishes" is wrong, and that it should be told like "to **do** the dishes". Is she right? If so, why is that?

Q2. Also she said "to **take** a rest" should be "to **get** a rest". Is she right?

Comment: Are you *sure* this person was a native speaker, and that you didn't misunderstand them?  I have no idea why a native speaker would say it is wrong to say **wash the dishes**; you can find it used frequently, as on [this page titled "How To Wash Dishes"](https://www.howtocleanstuff.net/how-to-wash-dishes/), and there is even a book titled [*How To Wash the Dishes*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/How_to_Wash_the_Dishes/PEfCDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22how+to+wash+dishes%22&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Then i'm relieved. I've used that expression a lot, too. I saw her speaking in an English-related show on Youtube months ago. But I can't find the video. Anyway, I'm clear now. Thank you for the help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1.I heard a native speaker say that the expression "to wash the dishes" is wrong, and that it should be told like "to do the dishes". Is she right? If so, why is that?**

**Both are commonly spoken** in the region where I come from. Why she says wash is wrong I am not sure.

However **possibly she commenting on what action is taking place**.

**"do the dishes"** (take care of the dirty dishes) is usually said when all the dishes remain on the table. Therefore the activity is more than just washing. It includes removal, cleaning waste into the litter bin, rinsing, washing, rinsing and drying. Alternatively you may have a dishwasher in which case you personally are not washing the dishes.

---

**Q2. Also she said "to take a rest" should be "to get a rest". Is she right?**

A lorry driver my have to **"take a rest"** because of his tachograph.

However I would say "**to have a rest**" is the more commonly used phrase or "**take a break**" or "**get some rest**"

Having said all that a snooker play would "**walk across to get a rest**" or he might stand up **"to take a rest"** to his partner.

The purpose of my last line being that **without context it is difficult to comment even without taking local dialects into account**.

---

**rest** noun (SUPPORT) **an object that supports the weight of something**:

Ref CED [**Rest**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rest)

Comment: Looks like my comment evaporated :) I appreciate your help, Mr Brad. I'm clear now:)